# How to export duplicate bone instances as an FBX?

Tags: rigging, export, armature, bones, unity

I'm trying to get this model I'm working on to export properly into Unity with no luck. Everything is exporting properly except the actual bones of the model, which aren't exporting at all (I have 'armature' checked on export settings.)

After a lot of failed attemps at exporting and re-exporting the model, I read a tooltip on the export settings menu that said I can't export 'duplicate instances' of armatures, which I am fairly certain is exactly what I have.

[image: Sorry she doesn't have materials, I drag them in in Unity]

See, I was trying to make a model for my 3D game that looks 2D (like in Paper Mario) out of planes, so I took individual bones and attached them to each part I wanted to animate (arm, leg, hand, ect.) rather than applying a traditional armature.

This is also why I can't use a program like Rigify to rig my model: the parts each need to move individually of one another, and a regular humanoid rig won't cut the job.

Do you have any suggestions for what I should do? When I import the .blend file into Unity, it looks like this:

[image: My poor, exploded antagonist]

And she still has all of her bones in the model.

But when I export the FBX, it looks like it should, with all of her limbs connected to her body, but the bones aren't there and I can't animate her.

Do you have any advice? I've been fiddling with this for days and have made very little progress; this is the first time I've animated a moving, human model.

Thanks so much.